# Property ... does not exist on type ... ( Angular ) - Editing item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm doing a test project and I came across the following problem.

I'm trying to edit an item in a list. But when trying to call the fields to be edited, I can't access the field information: read, write, delete, module. The message appears: Property ... does not exist on type , as shown in the image below:
[image: msg]

I know that my AllModules interface has this information that I want to access.
My Interface:

```js
export interface GrupoSegurancaInterface{
  id: string,
  name: string,
  branches: Branches,
  actions: AllModules[]
}


export interface Branches {
  id: number
  name:string
}

export interface AllModules {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  category: Category;
  read: boolean;
  write: boolean;
  delete: boolean
};

export interface Category {
  id: number;
  description: string;
};
```

I don't know what I could be doing wrong.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<mat-card class="matcardperfil">
  <mat-card-header class="matcardheader">
    <mat-card-title class="matcardtitle">Grupo de Segurança</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-tab-group fitInkBarToContent>
      <mat-tab label="Detalhes" class="mattabperfil">
        <form [formGroup]="form">
          <div class="tabmain">
            <mat-form-field class="matfield1" appearance="outline">
              <mat-label>Nome Grupo de Segurança</mat-label>
              <input matInput placeholder="" formControlName="name" />
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="matfield1" appearance="outline" required>
              <mat-label>Filiais</mat-label>
              <mat-select [formControl]="branchesControl" multiple>
                <mat-select-trigger>
                  <mat-chip-list formControlName="branches" ngDefaultControl>
                    <mat-chip
                      class="custom-chip-size"
                      *ngFor="
                        let topping of idsToToppings(branchesControl.value)
                      "
                      [removable]="true"
                      (removed)="onBranchesRemoved(topping)"
                    >
                      {{ topping }}
                      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
                    </mat-chip>
                  </mat-chip-list>
                </mat-select-trigger>
                <mat-option
                  *ngFor="let branches of selectedAllBranches"
                  [value]="branches.id"
                  >{{ branches.name }}</mat-option
                >
              </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Permissões">
        <section>
          <h4>Modulos do Grupo de Segurança</h4>
          <hr />
          <form [formGroup]="form">
            <div *ngFor="let category of allCategories" class="modulecheckbox">
              <h4>{{ category.description }}</h4>
              <div class="checkboxpermissions">
                <mat-checkbox
                  *ngFor="
                    let modules of filterItemsByCategory(
                      selectedAllModules,
                      category
                    )
                  "
                  [value]="modules.id.toString()"
                >
                  {{ modules.name }}
                  <div class="checkboxoptions">
                    <mat-checkbox
                      [(ngModel)]="modules.read"
                      formControlName="read"
                      >Leitura</mat-checkbox
                    >
                    <mat-checkbox
                      [(ngModel)]="modules.write"
                      formControlName="write"
                      >Escrita</mat-checkbox
                    >
                    <mat-checkbox
                      [(ngModel)]="modules.delete"
                      formControlName="delete"
                      >Exclusão</mat-checkbox
                    >
                  </div>
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </section>
        <hr />
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
    <mat-card-actions class="matcardactions">
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        style="color: white; background-color: #3f4b65"
        (click)="onSubmit()"
      >
        Salvar
      </button>
      <button
        mat-raised-button
        color="warn"
        class="buttonsenha"
        (click)="onCancel()"
      >
        Cancelar
      </button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

My Component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grupo-seguranca-form',
  templateUrl: './grupo-seguranca-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grupo-seguranca-form.component.scss']
})
export class GrupoSegurancaFormComponent implements OnInit {
  branchesControl = new FormControl<any>([]) ;
  selectedAllBranches: any = [];

   onBranchesRemoved(topping: any) {
    const toppings = this.branchesControl.value as string[] | any;
    this.removeFirst(toppings, topping);
    this.branchesControl.setValue(toppings); // To trigger change detection
  }


  idsToToppings(ids: number[]) : any[] {
    const names:string[] = []
      this.selectedAllBranches.filter((t:any) => ids.indexOf(t.id) > -1).forEach((element:any) => {
        names.push(element.name);

      });
      return names

    }


  @ViewChild('changeEl', { static: false }) changeEl?: MatSelect;

  selectedAllModules: AllModules[] =[];
  selectedModule:any = [];
  public selectItemBranch?: Observable<any>;
  form: UntypedFormGroup;
  valoresInput: any;
  selected: any = [];
  filteredItems : AllModules[] = [];
  allCategories : Category[]=[];

  private removeFirst<T>(array: T[], toRemove: T): void {
    const index = array.indexOf(toRemove);
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

    constructor(private _formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    private location : Location,
    private accountService: AccountService,
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private serviceGroup : GrupoSegurancaService) {


      this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        id: [null],
        name: [null, Validators.required],
        branches: [null,Validators.required],
        module: [null,Validators.required],
        read: [null,Validators.required],
        write: [null,Validators.required],
        delete: [null,Validators.required],

      })

    }


  seeMeBranch() {
    this.selected = this.accountService.meBranch().subscribe(
      resp => {
        this.selectedAllBranches = resp;
      });
  }


  seeMeModules() {
    this.selectedModule = this.serviceGroup.getAllModule().subscribe(
      resp => {
      this.selectedAllModules = resp;
      this.selectedAllModules.map(mod =>{
        mod.delete = !(mod.delete === undefined);
        mod.read = !(mod.read === undefined);
        mod.write = !(mod.write === undefined);
      })

       this.allCategories = this.filterGetAllCategories(resp)
      
      });

  }

  onSelectionChange(itemBranch: any) {
    this.selectItemBranch = itemBranch.value;
 }


  onCancel(){
    this.location.back();
  }


  filterItemsByCategory(data: AllModules[] ,category: Category) {
    return data.filter((item: AllModules) => {
      return item.category.id === category.id;
    })
  }


  filterGetAllCategories(data: AllModules[]) {
    const categorias : Category[]  = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (categorias.filter(cat=> cat.id === data[i].category.id).length === 0) {
        categorias.push(data[i].category);
      }
    }
    return categorias;
  }





ngOnInit(): void {

  this.seeMeBranch();
  this.seeMeModules();


 const data1: GrupoSegurancaInterface = this.route.snapshot.data['element']
      this.form.setValue({
      id: data1.id,
      name: data1.name,
      branches: data1.branches.id,
      module: data1.actions.id,
      read: data1.actions.read,
      write: data1.actions.write,
      delete: data1.actions.delete
      })
      console.log(data1)

  }


onSubmit(){
  this.valoresInput = this.form.value;
   let data = {
    "name": this.valoresInput.name,
    "branches": this.branchesControl.value.map((element:any) =>{
      return {
        "id" : element
            }
    })
    ,
    "actions": this.selectedAllModules.map((element:any) =>{
      return {
        "module":{
          "id": element.id
        },
        "read":element.read,
        "write": element.write,
        "delete":element.delete
      }
    })

     }
  
  this.serviceGroup.save(data).subscribe(result => this.onSucess(), erro => this.onError() );

}




private onError(){
  this.snackBar.open("Erro ao Salvar Grupo de Segurança","", { duration: 3000});
}

private onSucess(){
  this.snackBar.open("Grupo de Segurança salvo com Sucesso!","", {duration: 3000});
  this.onCancel();
}

}
```

My Service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GrupoSegurancaService {

  private readonly apiGroup = '/api/securitygroups';
  private readonly API = 'api/modules';


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  listAllGroups() {
    return this.httpClient.get<GrupoSegurancaInterface[]>(this.apiGroup)
      .pipe(
        first(),

      );
  }

  getAllModule() {
    return this.httpClient.get<AllModules[]>(`${this.API}`).pipe()
  }


  loadById(id: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get<GrupoSegurancaInterface>(`${this.apiGroup}/${id}`);
  }

  
  save(registro: any) {
    if (registro.id) {
      return this.update(registro);
    }
      return this.create(registro);
  }



  private create(registro: any) {
    return this.httpClient.post<GrupoSegurancaInterface>(`${this.apiGroup}`, registro)

  }

  private update(registro: any) {
    return this.httpClient.put<GrupoSegurancaInterface>(`${this.apiGroup}/${registro.id}`, registro)
  }

}
```

I researched in several places but unfortunately I couldn't solve it, I'm still learning and sometimes I have a little difficulty understanding

Comment: `actions` looks like it's an array. You need to specify which item you want. For example, `actions[0].id`

Comment: but I need to put [0] for the others ? like actions[0].read, actions[0].write, etc?
@evolutionxbox

Comment: Please avoid using images since they can't be read by screen readers, you should write the entire error for it to be accessible.

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't know about it. next time i will do it this way.
Thanks for the info @IgorCantele

Answer (score 0):

`actions` has the type of `AllModules[]`, so doesn't have any `id` etc... because it's an array of `AllModules`.

You could select for example the first action and do something like this, depending on what you want to display. This would look like:

```
const firstAction = data1.actions[0];
this.form.setValue({
  id: data1.id,
  name: data1.name,
  branches: data1.branches.id,
  module: firstAction.id,
  read: firstAction.read,
  write: firstAction.write,
  delete: firstAction.delete
})
```

Please note that this code will throw an error if the array is empty, so you want do do a check that it contains at least one element

```
if (data1.actions.length) {
    // see snippet above
} else {
    // what the form should look like if there are no data?
}
```